# Why $\frac{1}{z}$ is conformal as a Mobius transformation of the extended complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation, riemann-sphere

I vaguely understand, that $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ is conformal on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$, since it is a complex differentiable function.

Is it formally true? Since, basically $f: \hat{\mathbb{C}} \to \hat{\mathbb{C}}$ is a different beast from $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$.

The [claim](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Preservation_of_angles_and_generalized_circles) seems to imply, that $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ preserves angles (probably reversing orientation). In the same location it quotes

> For example, the preservation of angles is reduced to proving that
>   circle inversion preserves angles since the other types of
>   transformations are dilation and isometries (translation, reflection,
>   rotation), which trivially preserve angles.

But this is a treatment of the $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, if I understand correctly. Why a translation on the Riemann Sphere is an isometry, I have no clue. Why an isometry on the Riemann Sphere preserves angles, also I'm missing something.

Does $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ as an automorphism of $\hat{\mathbb{C}}$ actually preserve angles at $z = 0$? How can I prove this? Is it that Stereographic projection preserves angles? And an inversion is an inverse of Stereographic projection to the unit sphere, then rotation of unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and re-projection back to $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

- It follows from the Cauchy-Riemann equation that any holomorphic map $f: U \to \mathbb C$ (with $U$ an open subset of $\mathbb C$) is conformal on $U$ if and only if its derivative doesn't vanish on $U$. Here the angles are measured in the standard hermitian metric on $\mathbb C$ (which is also the euclidean metric on $\mathbb R^2$).
- In particular, $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ is conformal on $\mathbb C^*$. Also, it preserves orientation, as do all holomorphic map.
- Any isometry preserves angles; but preserving angles doesn't imply being an isometry (think of the map $f(z)=2z$ on $\mathbb C$).
- A translation is certainly not an isometry for the spherical metric, but it is clearly one for the euclidean metric on $\mathbb C$.
- It is possible to prove that the only holomorphic maps $f: \hat{\mathbb C} \to \hat{\mathbb C}$ whose derivatives do not vanish are Mobius transformations $M(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$.
- Any pair of hermitian metrics on the same Riemann surface (in particular the Riemann sphere) define the same angles (but not necessarily the same distances). So for angle-preserving, you can actually forget about metrics (as long as you only work with hermitian metrics of course). Then it follows from the first bullet point that any holomorphic map $f: S_1 \to S_2$ between Riemann surfaces preserves angles if and only if its derivative doesn't vanish. You can work this out by using charts.

Comment: So what happens at $0$? Suppose, I have $g(z) = \frac{1}{z} \circ (z+2) \circ \frac{1}{z}$. and $|z - i|=1$, $|z+1|=1$ - two circles, which crosses at $0$. Their images under $g$ also crosses at $0$, and still seems to be orthogonal. Is it a lucky a coincidence?

Comment: @dEmigOd like I wrote, any Mobius transformation is conformal, so no it's not a lucky coincidence. See the last bullet point